# obtaining components of plot from rms calibrate

Tags: r

Are the values for the plot available from rms calibrate? From ?calibrate

```
library("rms")
set.seed(1)
n <- 200
d.time <- rexp(n)
x1 <- runif(n)
x2 <- factor(sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), n, TRUE))
f <- cph(Surv(d.time) ~ pol(x1,2) * x2, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, surv=TRUE,time.inc=1.5)
cal <- calibrate(f, u=1.5, cmethod='KM', m=50, B=20)
plot(cal)
cal
```

I would like to obtain the values that make up this plot. The y-values can be seen on the screen, but it is not clear to me how to obtain the x and y values. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the result of `attributes(cal)` ?  There is still a bit of work to do to pull out what you need.

Comment: Exactly which values to you want to extract? Do you want just the x/y values for the dots? Those are `cal[, "mean.predicted"]` for x values and  `cal[, "KM"]` for y values. You can verify this by running `points(cal[, "mean.predicted"], cal[, "KM"], col="red")`

Comment: @MrFlick You are right. It looks like the bins used to form the values are not directly available, which is another item I was looking for. But your comment answers my question. I can accept it if you want to move it to an answer.